OTEL_PYTHON_LOG_CORRELATION is not logging when set to true
I have mentioned OTEL_PYTHON_LOG_CORRELATION: true & OTEL_PYTHON_LOG_FORMAT:"" in my aws cloudformation template under lambda's env variables but i don't see any logs related to that y is it?
from opentelemetry.trace import get_current_span


def set_span_attr(key, value):
    get_current_span().set_attribute(key, value)


